# Creating Bat file to execute a command on all files in folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I need to run this command line program on every xlsx file with a few parameters:

`"C:\temp\cnv.exe" "param1" "param2" "param3"`, where

- param1-complete path to *.xlsx file, also searched file(ex. "D:\temp\sample1.xlsx");
- param2-complete path to output folder, should be the same for the current file(ex. "D:\temp\");
- param3-static wording("-layout").

started from, but don't know how to finish:

`cd "d:\temp\"
for /r %%i in (*.xlsx) do "C:\temp\cnv.exe" "%%i"........ "-layout"?`

Comment: The modifiers can be viewed when entering `for /?` at the Command Prompt. You may wish to use one which expands `%%i`  to its drive and path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do the `cd` with `/R` switch:

```
for /r "D:\Temp" %%i in (*.xlsx) do "C:\temp\cnv.exe" "%%i" "%%~dpi" -layout
```

Only the command with it's path `c:\temp\cnv.exe` and the paths should be double quoted (in case it contains whitespace) `-layout` and any other `-` switch does not require double quoting.

Comment: for `output folder, should be the same for the current file` replace `"D:\temp\"` with `"%%~dpi"`

Comment: I did end up using:   `for /r "D:\Temp" %%i in (*.xlsx) do "C:\temp\cnv.exe" "%%i" "%%~dpi" -layout`  Thanks to @Gerhard and @Stephan,

Comment: @stephan. Thanks, i never even notices that comment. Changed it :)

Comment: Any suggestions for batch-processing resource? Maybe something with examples, something other than standard win cmd help. Thank you :)

Comment: @lino. Best resource is on your pc. Run `cmd /?` it will fie you all commands. Simply run each command with the `/?` switch for help on each.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not using it now, but when you are ready to use PowerShell, this might be a starting point.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.csv |
    ForEach-Object { & C:\temp\exe `"$_.FullName1" `"$_.DirectoryName`" -layout }
```